# how to account for menubar height when active rendering?

Tags: java, swing

I am working on a physics simulator and am using swing to render. I wanted to improve the interface by adding a menu-bar and other components. However, when I try and clip the drawing are, the height of the menu bar isn't take into account, and as a result my drawing is shifted higher than it should 
Here is some sample code to illustrate:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
public class TestFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public TestFrame() {
        initComponents();
    }        

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        //initalize and show the frame
        TestFrame frame= new TestFrame();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        //creat buffer strategy
        frame.createBufferStrategy(2);
        BufferStrategy bufferStrategy = frame.getBufferStrategy();

        //loop through rendering loop
        while(true)
        {
            //get the graphics context to draw on
            Graphics2D drawGraphics=(Graphics2D) bufferStrategy.getDrawGraphics();
            frame.paint(drawGraphics);

            Rectangle bounds=frame.drawingPanel.getBounds();

            //account for frame's insets
            Insets insets=frame.getInsets();
            bounds.x+=insets.left;
            bounds.y+=insets.top;
            Border border = frame.drawingPanel.getBorder();

            //account for the Border's insets
            insets=border.getBorderInsets(frame.drawingPanel);
            bounds.x+=insets.left;
            bounds.y+=insets.top;
            bounds.width-=insets.left+insets.right;
            bounds.height-=insets.top+insets.right;

            //draw a test rectangle            
            drawGraphics.setColor(new Color(0,255,0,64));
            drawGraphics.fill(bounds);

            //show rendering and then dispose
            bufferStrategy.show();
            drawGraphics.dispose();
        }
    }
    private javax.swing.JPanel drawingPanel;
    private javax.swing.JMenu editMenu;
    private javax.swing.JMenu fileMenu;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar menuBar;
 }
```

The contents of `initComponents()`:

```
private void initComponents() {

        drawingPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        menuBar = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        fileMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        editMenu = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        drawingPanel.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder(javax.swing.border.BevelBorder.RAISED));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout drawingPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(drawingPanel);
        drawingPanel.setLayout(drawingPanelLayout);
        drawingPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            drawingPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        drawingPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            drawingPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 100, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        fileMenu.setText("File");
        menuBar.add(fileMenu);

        editMenu.setText("Edit");
        menuBar.add(editMenu);

        setJMenuBar(menuBar);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(drawingPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(284, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(drawingPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(162, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }
```

The other option I can think of is to have the drawing code be located in the `paint` method of the `jPanel`.

Comment: Your loop for rendering looks awfully suspicious. It will pretty much eat up your resources. Calling repaint when the drawing is modified should be enough. Possibly you may want a Swing Timer to repaint regularly.

Comment: I have omitted the code that updates the state of my objects from the code as I was having issues with rendering the position correctly. In the rendering loop I have it update the object states and then draw them.

Comment: You have things backwards. Your model must modify itself and then notify the views so that they repaint themselves. Here you do the opposite, you have your views that update the model and then repaint themselves. `repaint()` can be invoked by the OS, but it should mainly be your code that invokes that. A while(true) loop that constantly repaints your view is really not the way to go.

Comment: my model is being updated 600 times per second. I need to have the drawing and modifying occur in a synchronized manner so as to avoid half of my model being updated and the other half in it's previous state.

Comment: Your statement is contradictory and the way you implemented even more: You can be pretty sure that your loop cannot be executed 600 times per second. Either you need those 600/seconds and making a while(true) loop is actually a very good way to make sure you will never achieve that. If you want it to refresh very fast and sometimes update the display: then use ThreadPool's to update your model, use a Swing Timer to update your view. Use a common object to synchronize your model and your view in order to avoid half-updated models.

Comment: In all cases, the human eye does not see any difference over 30 refresh per second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The other option I can think of is to have the drawing code be located in the `paint` method of the `jPanel`.

Yes, but use `paintComponent`.

```
public class PhysicsPanel extends JPanel {
// (or extend JComponent if you don't need to `add` anything)

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        // painting code
    }
}
```

Then just add a `PhysicsPanel` to your main frame; `repaint` on the frame will repaint the physics panel as well.

Comment: This is the standard recommendation, but may not apply when using active rendering as the original poster stated he is doing.

Comment: I use this for active rendering and it works fine (assuming by "active rendering" you mean a `while` loop and drawing on a `Canvas` with a buffer strategy).

Comment: I had seen in several places to not put drawing code in the paint method so i assumed it applied to the other painting methods as well. By "active rendering" I mean that I am having the the program update its state and then draw it as opposed to waiting for the OS to send a repaint message.